How to push a named local branch to a particular branch (of different name) in a remote repository
Is there a straightforward way to push a named local branch to a branch of a different name in a remote repository?
Currently, I have a complicated script which my students are supposed to run to do this action.  But things go wrong, which my students are not advanced enough to explain.
I have created a remote branch named grader and the branch on the remote repository is named master.  However, the local repository has a branch named submission.   I want to push the branch submission to the grader repository onto the branch named master.
Here are the commands which were done, initially.  But I suspect (without proof) that the VSCode git interface sometimes changes things.
git branch submission
git checkout submission
git push grader submission:master
git branch --set-upstream-to=grader/master submission
git config push.default upstream

Sometimes, there might be something already on the remote branch, if the student has run the process before.
So in this case, the script that the student runs does the following:
git checkout submission
git branch --set-upstream-to=grader/master submission
git config push.default upstream
git merge -m 'repairing remote' --strategy=ours --allow-unrelated-histories grader/master
git push grader submission:master

Later on, the student pushes to the repository with the commands. The text of the tag, xyzzy, may change depending on the context.
git commit -am 'commiting for tag xyzzy'
git branch
git branch -r
git remote -v
git status
git tag xyzzy
git push
git push --tags

The error message that sometimes occurs is the following
You are not allowed to push code to this project

or sometimes
fatal: the current branch submission has no upstream branch

From that message, I cannot know which remote repository it tried to push to.
I wish the error message told me which repository was missing an upstream branch.
There are so many possible things that might have gone wrong.  It would be nice if there were a single command line which would just push the named local branch to a named branch on a named remote repository, and would not depend on the state of the current repository.

"a single command line which would just push the named local branch to a named branch on a named remote repository, and would not depend on the state of the current repository." I might have misunderstood what you need, but git push --force grader submission:master will push on the remote with a single command, overwriting the content on the remote with the one on the local repository.

The message You are not allowed to push code to this project is not produced by git. It must be an error that the remote repository reports, most likely when a user connects to the incorrect upstream repository that they do not have push permissions.

@dani-vta thanks for the suggestion.  Can you please clarify something for future readers of the post.   in your example git push --force grader submission:master,
grader is the name of the remote repository, submission is the name of the local branch to push and master is the desired name of the branch on the remote repository.  Right?

@j6t I've recently learned that the message You are not allowed to push code to this project is a message from GitLab.

@dani-vta, oops there's a problem with your suggestion.   We cannot use --force for master branch
remote: Push force is not allowed on the master branch, rejecting

@JimNewton In your question you wrote "would not depend on the state of the current repository". If you don't want to take the current state of the repository into account, you have very little choice, if not to force push. Instead if you cannot force push but need to merge/align the commit histories, then you do depend on the current state of the repo. You need to pick one of the two and re-prhase your question accordingly. So far, it's not clear what you need.

@dani-vta, you ask for a better explanation. I need to push a commit to the remote repository (named grader) onto its branch named master, so that if anyone checks out that branch he'll see the same set of files and contents of files as I have checked in as the head of the local branch named submission.    Perhaps that's not possible with a single git command.  If not, then that's the answer: it's not possible.  In which case, I'm happy to receive approximate solutions/suggestions.

It's possible: git push -f grader submission:master.

@mkrieger1, the reason I (the OP) didn't believe it is because I tried it and it failed.  I'm not allowed to use --force on the master branch.

Yes, but that's because there's another problem preventing it. It doesn't mean that it's impossible.

I never said it was impossible.  I'll be happy if anyone can suggest a way which actually works.
